# How to join strings with a space without adding an extra space at the end?

Tags: python, string

I am need to make a code which counts the number of specific type of letters in a sentence and also print out the words that contain the specific letter. however, i can't have a whitespace at the end of it. So far my code is:

```
a = input("Letter: ")
b = input("Input: ")
a=a.lower()
b=b.lower()
c=b.count(a)
print(c)
words = b.split()
for word in words:
    if a in word:
        print(word, end=' ')
```

which gives the output:

```
Letter: e
Input: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3
the over the
```

However there is a whitespace after the 'the'. Could you suggest a code which removes this whitespace.

Thanks

Comment: No it is not a duplicate of that. The question's title is misleading. The OP's problem is joining strings with a space without having a space  at the end (title edit under review).

Comment: @HugoWood Agreed. Thanks for pointing out. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `join` here (so that no whitespace is added after your last word). Rewrite the for-loop as

```
' '.join([word for word in words if a in word])
```

**EDIT**

Your code would be

```
a = input("Letter: ") 
b = input("Input: ") 
a=a.lower() 
b=b.lower() 
c=b.count(a) 
print(c) 
words = b.split() 
print ' '.join([word for word in words if a in word])
```

Comment: +1 for actually reading the OP's code and understanding their problem

Comment: i replaced the for-loop with what you suggested so my code looks like this:

Comment: a = input("Letter: ")
b = input("Input: ")
a=a.lower()
b=b.lower()
c=b.count(a)
print(c)
words = b.split()
word=' '.join([word for word in words if a in word])
if a in word:
  print(word, end=' ')

Comment: Yet, my out put is still like this:                                          Letter: e
Input: he quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
3
he over the

Comment: so it still has a whitespace at the end of the 'the'

Comment: You should replace the entire 3 lines of the for loop with the one statement in my answer, so: `a = input("Letter: ") b = input("Input: ") a=a.lower() b=b.lower() c=b.count(a) print(c) words = b.split() print ' '.join([word for word in words if a in word])`

Comment: 1 last thing. I just realised that i need to count the number of words that contain the specific letter, no the number of specific letters in the input. For example, if the ouput is:

Comment: Letter: e
Input: ee eeeee is
7
ee eeeee

Comment: instead of saying 7, it should say 2 as there is 2 words that contain the letter e. I am i making any sense?

Comment: That is a separate question from the one you posed in your original question, but you could start by changing your code so that you count the number of words that contain the letter at least once, instead of counting all occurrences, for example with `c=b.count([word for word in words if a in word])`.

Comment: Thank you once again. I have only started coding last week and you have really helped me.

Comment: Glad to help :) Since my answer was helpful, I would really appreciate it if you can set it to 'accepted'

Comment: Sorry, i started using SO today. How do you make it 'accepted'.

Comment: Just click on the checkmark underneath the number next to my answer.